# Xlsxwriter, formatting just some cells, not whole row or whole column?

Tags: python, formatting, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe that I am sending to Excel using the xlsxwriter engine, then applying formatting to a sheet before closing it. How can I only set a bg color for the columns that have data in them?

For example, I am able to add a yellow background color to the second column (below), but it extends past the cells that have data in them. I am doing this with set_column() as below:

```
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 18, hilite_format)
```

I don't see an option to set column format for only certain rows, or to use set_row() to only format certain columns. I've already written the data to the worksheet, so I can't use worksheet.write() or it will overwrite the data that is already in there. At least I don't see any way to use .write() to just apply the formatting without writing data or None into the cells.

Is there a way to just 'paint' some formatting over a range of cells without affecting the values in those cells? I would prefer not to have to use conditional formatting or to re-write the data for these cells just to be able to get the formatting right.

Thank!

[image]

Comment: There is not way at the time of writing to change a format of an already "written" cell using Xlsxwriter. It's a feature-request, but it's not a priority. I think the only feasible thing to do for you is to use conditional formatting, just as @LuanNaufal  already has given you the code for.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the conditional_format(), highlighting the cells that are not blank:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B:B', {'type': 'no_blanks',
                                     'format': hilite_format})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

- You put your logic here and use whenever you want in cell.

  `merge_format = workbook.add_format({
          'border': 1,
          'align': 'center',
          'valign': 'vcenter'})`

  worksheet.merge_range('A1:R1', 'AGENCIES', merge_format)